# return true not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am little bit new to `jQuery`. I have jQuery code as follow :

```
function callfunction() {
  var email = $("#email").val();
  var passwrd = $("#password").val();
  $.ajax({
    url: "checklogin.php?email="+email+"&pass="+passwrd,
    type: "post",
    success: function (response) {
      if(response == '1') {
        alert('Login Successfull. Proceed to pay now');
        $('#getre').show();
        $('#signuplink').hide();
        $('#password2').hide();
        $('#login').hide();
        $('#email').attr('disabled','disabled');
        return true;
      }
      if(response == '0') {
        alert('Login Failed !!! Try Again');
        return false;
      }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
  });
}
```

and its HTML code is as follow :

```
<form class='form form-inline' style="margin-top:20px;" method="post" 
action="#">
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="amount form-control required" Placeholder="Enter Email ID"  required="">
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="amount form-control required" Placeholder="Enter Password" required="">
  <input type="submit" name="getr" class="mob-btn btn btn-primary btn-info-full" value="Login" onClick="return callfunction()">
</form>
```

When I am submitting the form and `response ==0` then the form is submitting the data while I dont want to submit the data is `response=0`.

How I can achieve this ?

Comment: You can't utilize Asynchronus programming that way.

Comment: `$.ajax` is async, so `callfunction` will return before it received a response. Your only option is to always have it return false, and trigger the submit in the case you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take out `type="submit"` from your submit button element. This will prevent the form from being submitted before the ajax request is fired off.

```
<input name="getr" class="mob-btn btn btn-primary 
        btn-info-full" value="Login" onClick="callfunction()">
```

then when you receive your ajax response you can call `form.submit()` like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "checklogin.php?email="+email+"&pass="+passwrd,
    type: "post",
    success: function (response) {
     if(response == '1')
     {

         $('.form-inline').submit();
         alert('Login Successfull. Proceed to pay now');

         $('#getre').show();
         $('#signuplink').hide();
         $('#password2').hide();
         $('#login').hide();
         $('#email').attr('disabled','disabled');
     }
     if(response == '0')
     {
         alert('Login Failed !!! Try Again');
     }

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```